# How do you add more space to a Fedora (LVM) partition?

Tags: virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine, fedora, lvm

In a nutshell, i have a VM that ran out of space. I increased the size of the VM's harddrive to be 4 times bigger but the OS partition is still only using 1x the space. I need to change the LVM partition to take up the extra 4x space but I don't know how to extend the LVM partition.

(NOTE: To make the screenshots given below I had to boot from a live-cd for gnome-partition-manager (aka gparted). [Very unfortunately gparted is only able to "detect LVM" and can't do any LVM operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted#Supported_features).)

Here is what "gparted" shows. Please notice that the "resize" option is not available:

[image]

---

### The Problem:

**I can't find good directions<1> on how to grow the LVM partition via GUI or command-line! How do you grow a LVM partition that was created by the default Fedora install?**

If you are giving command line directions. Please explain what each line of commands does.

Comment: Anyone who does a default fedora install has this partition setup, I'm surprised no one else has run into this problem... fedora has such a large install base of users.

Comment: *Update*: I marked one of the answers as correct. I was unable to verify that the answer marked as correct worked on my VM... the process was to complex for me to get working.

Comment: *Update*: I ended up backing up data. Creating a new VM from scratch and restoring the data.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I thought I used to do this with system-config-lvm GUI tool in CentOS, but it's not working for me today. So I had to go old school. As always, this might destroy your data, so MAKE A BACKUP!!  Thanks to experts across the internet for providing these hints. Unfortunately my notes do not include attribution details. Note I performed all of these changes while the system was live.

1. Enlarge the disk using fdisk

   1. `fdisk -l`               (to see the partition layout, typically we're dealing with /dev/sda2)
   2. `fdisk /dev/sda`
   3. `d`                    (delete a partition)
   4. `2`                    (if the part we want to grow is /dev/sda2; note this does not delete any data on disk)
   5. `n`                    (create a new partition)
   6. `p`                    (primary partition)
   7. `2`
   8. `<return>`          (default starting block, typically 14 since swap is first)
   9. `<return>`          (default ending block, full size of the partition)
   10. make sure partition type is 8e for Linux LVM

       1. `t`
       2. `8e`
   11. `w`                    (write changes to disk)
2. reboot                                                                            to get new partition table
3. `pvresize /dev/sda2`
4. `pvscan` should show new larger size
5. `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/vg_centos6/lv_root`            (-L +10G to add 10GB is another option)
6. `resize2fs /dev/vg_centos6/lv_root`
7. `df` should show new free space

Comment: perfect , when we want resize root partition , we just need boot with boot.iso (for example http://mirrors.eu.kernel.org/fedora/releases/18/Fedora/x86_64/os/images/boot.iso) -> troubleshoot -> rescue (after choose 3rd option not mount) -> shell and do yours instructions :)

Comment: I love you! I've spent hours trying to do just this!

Answer (score 1):

The command [lvextend](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lvextend) can help you. For instance,

```
lvextend -L +54 /dev/vg01/lvol10 /dev/sdk3
```

tries to extend the size of that logical volume by 54MB on physical volume /dev/sdk3. This is only possible if /dev/sdk3 is a member of volume group vg01 and there are enough free physical extents in it.

Comment: i would love to get a little bit more... i'm guessing that calling this command by itself without any input arguments would probably not fix the problem.

Comment: how do you know to use "/dev/vg01/lvol10". where did you get that from?

Comment: why did you put "/dev/sdk3"?

Comment: Sorry, i was busy. The /dev/sdk3 is the physical volume of your machine. For instance, for you, it might /dev/sda2. The /dev/vg01/lvol10

Comment: Hi, sorry I was busy. This command is for example purpose only. It depends how do you install lvm in your system. The /dev/vg01/lvol01 is the logical volume 01 on the volume group 01. The /dev/sdk3 is the partition where the volume group is installed. In your case, the physical partition is /dev/sda2. So you must find what the volume group associated with this partition. http://bobcares.com/blog/?p=137

Comment: that blog posting will probably solve what i need. but FML... the post is so damn long. when i get around to reading it and trying it... i will maybe repost here.