# Cloned Linux does not recognize the new flash drive's space?

Tags: linux, partitioning, usb-flash-drive, centos-6, gparted

I installed CentOS 6 into my 4GB flash drive, and everything worked fine until I needed more space. I have another flash drive with 8GB of space (which is all I really need) and so I formatted it with **gparted** to ext4. Once it was done formatting I went into the Terminal and put this command:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=512 conv=noerror,sync
```

Up to this point everything worked correctly, and once the command was finished (took less than an hour), I went ahead and rebooted, removing my old flash drive. Once it booted in with the new flash drive I was extremely happy that everything worked flawlessly until I went to install some packages with YUM, and I only have 12.5 MB of free space remaining!

I went back into **gparted** and this is the "screen shot" of it:
[image: Screenshot]

I am assuming that I somehow need to extend one of the partions and remove the *unallocated*, but I don't know how. 
Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Just choose the option to extend it.

Comment: @Ramhound could you elaborate?

Comment: Right Click on the `/dev/sdb2` bar and there should be an option to Extend Partition.

Comment: @MichaelFrank http://postimg.org/image/8lxgdene9/ I don't have that option, unfortunately.

Comment: See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/269045/how-to-merge-an-unallocated-partition-with-an-extended-partition

Comment: Oh, so I HAVE to boot from the gparted live CD? Because I've just been using the app I installed via YUM.

Comment: When you dd, you copy everything, bit by bit, which means you copied the partition table from your old drive to the new drive.  And yes, you should boot from a different environment than the one you're trying to modify as you can't modify a mounted partition.

Comment: @Ernie okay I understand now I didn't know I had to be booted in a different environment. So which partion am I supposed to extend exactly?

Comment: Since you are using LVM, this is not as simple as just using gparted. Have a look at this:

http://superuser.com/questions/335038/how-do-you-add-more-space-to-a-fedora-lvm-partition

Comment: @GregBowser I have tried the answer in that question and it didn't do anything..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much easier solution to your problem, *i.e.* use **Clonezilla**. Clonezilla is a free program for disk cloning and data recovery; you find a very detailed account of how to do it [here](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/03_Disk_to_disk_clone). The advantage of this method is that you can circumvent the need of a *third* medium (USB/DVD) which seems instead to emerge from the previous comments.

Since you cannot use the disks you wish to use, but you also need to use a medium to host Clonezilla, it *appears* you need three media. However, the reference above instructs on how to mount Clonezilla on the empty new, large disk, boot from it thanks to Clonezilla, then load all of Clonezilla into RAM so that disk space on the new medium can be freed, and used to clone the smaller disk onto the larger one, in the meantime enlarging the partitions as you wish.

The instructions above are very detailed. Notice, though, that when you are offered the 
option **Beginner/Expert**, you **must** choose Expert because:

> By deafult, Clonezilla will clone the "same" size of source disk to target disk. i.e. in this example, only 8 GB will be cloned to target disk, so the rest of 12 GB on the destination disk will be unallocated. If you want to make use all of the target disk size, remember to enter "Expert" mode and choose option "-k1".

That's really all there is to it. But remember: with a target disk size of 1T, it will take you several hours.

Comment: I ended up just reinstalling Linux on that flash drive, but I'm sure this will help other people with a similar problem,