# Can't clone SSD with a Windows partition and a Linux partition

Tags: partitioning, windows-8.1, ssd, ubuntu-14.04, acronis-trueimage

I recently installed with some effort Zorin OS (based on Ubuntu LTS 14.04) on another partition of my Intel SSD 335 (240 gb in total) and divided that other partition many smaller partitions of the ext4, ext3 sorts. (Perhaps not using the right terminology but pardon me I am selftaught). Now because of the fact that my Zorin OS needs more space I purchased myself at a very nice discount a Samsung 840 Pro SSD (size 512 gb) which will replace my Intel drive.

I tried to use Acronis True Image to clone the Intel drive to the Samsung drive without success.

The error I am getting is that the True Image software says that it cannot read one of the partitions an thus the cloning is not completed.

What should I do?

The Intel SSD boots and shows me the bootmenu that I presume is on the linux partition and not the Windows 8.1 Pro partition.

Comment: There is a much simpler solution, see this answer http://superuser.com/questions/838401/cloned-linux-does-not-recognize-the-new-flash-drives-space/838749#838749

Comment: Just explain to me the following answers
Q1: Why not Acronis True Image live USB but CloneZilla instead ?
Q2: What are exactly in your opinion the stronger points for CloneZilla versus Acronis True Image ?

Comment: Clonezilla is easier to use, faster, can be installed on the new medium from which you boot, then load it into memory and erase the new medium for the installation: saves one install medium (usb, dvd). Also, it is faster, nothing comes close.

Comment: Well I have used CloneZilla as you recommended and it got the work done. I must say however that i do not find it quite intuitive to work with. But hell.. that is I guess a learning curve I must go through.

Comment: Good to hear. If you found it useful, please upvote the answer I referenced above

Comment: Marius, I wish I could do that but I have not yet gained the status to rate your solution

Answer (score -1):

If I were you I'd booted a live cd distro, and use `dd` to clone old drive to the new one, then use `gparted` to create new partition(s) on free space of new drive.