# Fedora 29 boots into dracut emergency shell after resizing root partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, fedora, dracut

I resized the root filesystem on Fedora 29 in VirtualBox from 15GB to 20GB but can no longer get it to boot.  It always lands in the dracut emergency shell.  After first resizing the VDI and the snapshots in VirtualBox, I enlarged the disks as per steps 1.1 to 1.11 according to the accepted answer on [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/335038/how-do-you-add-more-space-to-a-fedora-lvm-partition).  I was executing step 2 (reboot) when I hit the problem.

Running `blkid` I see `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`.  I have mounted `/dev/sda1` in Fedora Live and can see that it is the boot partition, so can edit the grub configuration if I wanted to, but I can find no way of mounting `/dev/sda2`.  LVM reports no devices.

There is a difference in the output of `blkid` for the two devices.  While `/dev/sda1` reports `UUID`, `TYPE` and `PARTUUID` I only see `PARTUUID` on `/dev/sda2`.  When I deleted and re-created the partition with `fdisk`, did it wipe out some metadata that LVM needs?  Any idea how I can get this system booting again?

Comment: In 1.8, did you take care to use the very same starting sector as before? or did you just hit Enter? The answer makes a silent (inelegant IMO) assumption the default values are right. Compare [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1446923/432690) where it says `The partition in question was recreated larger but its starting sector remained`. In your case LVM is an additional layer but the general rule stands: enlarging a partition to the right by deleting and re-creating it requires the left end (starting sector) to stay put. Is it possible you changed the starting sector?

Comment: Yes the starting sector was exactly right, I triple-checked it before I wrote the changes and also confirmed it again from Fedora Live once boot-up had been broken.  Definitely a good question to ask, but not the problem in this case.

Comment: I have got the system booting now, I ended up comparing the first couple of KB of the disk device using `dd` with that of the same device from an earlier snapshot taken a month ago when I was still running FC23.  I found that the `lvm_type` field in the `LABEL_HEADER` had been zeroed out!  I'm not sure why `fdisk` would have done that and I wasn't sure if there was a "proper" way to fix it, but a quick binary edit and `dd` the modified block back to disk and hey presto the missing volumes reappeared in `/dev/mapper` and could be mounted. I will try to reproduce this and post a proper analysis.

Comment: You are not saying what exactly you did to extend your filesystem. Also the exact error message is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question just in case others hit the same problem in the future.  The primary reason I encountered this issue was because `fdisk` has been modified slightly since [the post](https://superuser.com/questions/335038/how-do-you-add-more-space-to-a-fedora-lvm-partition) I was following and so I was asked a question that I was not expecting (i.e. a question not mentioned in the instructions that I was following) and I also answered that question poorly.

`fdisk` will now alert you to the presence of an `LVM2_member` signature and will ask you if you wish to remove it:

```
Partition #2 contains a LVM2_member signature.

Do you want to remove the signature? [Y]es/[N]o:
```

Unfortunately, and for reasons I won't go into now but you can read my full blog post on it that I'll link to below, I answered `Y` to this.  Unsurprisingly, this then zeroed the 64-bit `lvm_type` field in the `LABEL_HEADER` on the disk, leaving me with a system that would no longer boot and would instead dump me rather unceremoniously inside the dracut emergency shell.

The solution was to write that 64-bit header back to the disk.  I couldn't find a tool that would do this for me, so I used `dd` from within Fedora Live to read the first couple of blocks from the disk into a file, I edited the file with `vi -b` and then wrote it back to the disk again with `dd`.  I knew exactly which bytes to edit because I compared the output of `od -Ax -tx1z -v <filename>` with a copy from an earlier snapshot that I had available.  Note that the Fedora Live image I was working in did not have `xxd` available.  After re-adding the missing signature, LVM immediately recognised the disk and I was able to mount my volumes again.

Because the full explanation and procedure is quite long, I blogged about it.  If you've found yourself in a similar predicament, you might find my notes useful which you can view [here](https://technicalprose.blogspot.com/2020/01/dracut-emergency-lvm-label-missing.html).

Comment: Oh well, if you use LVM and wipe the PV signature from the disk, it's nor surprising that the kernel cannot find the LVs (also PV, VG) any more. BTW: LVM creates backups in `/etc/lvm/backup` automatically after a change (using `vgcfgbackup`) that you can restore using `vgcfgrestore`.